# Perl if statement without equality

Tags: perl

I am reading through code that looks like

```
$value = 1.0 - $value if $indx;
```

but I want it in the form

```
if ($indx == 0) {
    $value = 1.0 - $value;
 }
```

However, the second code sample isn't a correct translation of the first.   There should be some operator after the `if $indx` statement (I like complete sentences). How can I write the first code sample like the second sample?

Comment: you have made two changes; one is changing from using an if statement modifier to an if statement, and the other is changing from testing if $indx is true to testing if it is numerically equal to 0.  from your question, it seems like you only intended one of these changes, but I am not sure which?

Comment: @ysth I am trying to write an if statement equivalent of the first code segment

Comment: Simply add parentheses around the condition: `if ($indx) { $value = 1.0 - $value; }`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You start off with the postfix conditional form:

```
$value = 1.0 - $value if $indx;
```

To translate that the block form, you have:

```
if( $indx ) {
   $value = 1.0 - $value 
   }
```

Both of these subtract `$value` from 1.0 if the value in `$indx` is true. In Perl, "true" is anything that is not false, and false is one of these values: 0, '0', the empty string, undef, and the empty list.

You can't test for any particular true value because there are so many of them. The original code wants to execute that expression for any true value.

You can check that you don't have a false value though. Using the numerical not-equal operator will coerce the value of undef to the numeric value 0:

```
if( $indx != 0 ) {
   $value = 1.0 - $value 
   }
```

Similarly, you can check that you have a false value and negate that:

```
if( !($indx == 0) ) {
   $value = 1.0 - $value 
   }
```

This is why your translation doesn't work. You start by running the code if the value in `$indx` is true to running the code if the value if false. You've flipped the test.

But, this is really a lot of work when the postfix conditional (the way that apparently works in the old code) is the Perly way to do it.

You don't say why you want it in another form. Perhaps you are trying to run additional statements. No matter what you want to do, you need to preserve the test.

Comment: Could also use `unless` with the OP's backwards conditional.

Comment: FALSE: The number `0`, the strings`'0'` and `''` (the empty string), the empty list `()`, and `undef`

Comment: ah yes, left out the empty string. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = 1.0 - $value if $indx == 0;
```

Comment: This doesn't give the correct answer (this is a small part of a much larger program)

Comment: `unless $index==0` or `if $index != 0`